# Winter Summer Bash Hat list is not displayed on a user's profile if you don't have a profile on the site

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, design, winter-bash, winter-bash-2022

I'm not a member of the politics stack. [An awesome user](https://politics.stackexchange.com/users/28994/cdjb?tab=summary) has some hats I was hoping to browse, but I'm not prepared to join the Politics site at this time.

Why do they show like this:
[image: badges in summary section]

Comment: I can highly recommend the politics stack :)

Comment: Oh, hey... it's said awesome user. :D

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Winter Bash is an event for logged-in users only and this is intentional. We don't want to clutter up the UI for people who can't make it go away - non-logged-in users do not have a "no hats for me" button. As such, if you're not logged in on a site, you will not see the hat UI on that site. I'm not completely sure but I think this includes the snowflake in the top bar.

As a note, you can always join the site and, if you don't post anything, you can delete your profile there instantly with no issues.

Comment: Any chance it can be shown if one's logged into the SE network at large, but not the specific site (i.e., the button shows as "Join this community" instead of "Sign up")?

Comment: Not going to change it this year - we're in bug fix only phase and this isn't a bug. I'm not sure if it's possible to change.

Comment: @Catija what about showing all of them in the winter bash website? Instead of the most recent N.